# Does lintian also check for differences between policy levels in a given package?

Tags: debian, lintian

Lintian description is as below (taken from `$ aptitude show lintian` on Debian testing ) -

```
Description: Debian package checker
 Lintian dissects Debian packages and reports bugs and policy violations. It contains automated checks for many aspects of Debian policy as well as some checks for common errors. 

 It uses an archive directory, called laboratory, in which it stores information about the packages it examines. It can keep this information between multiple invocations in order to avoid repeating expensive data-collection operations. This makes it possible to check the complete Debian archive for bugs, in a reasonable time. 

 This package is useful for all people who want to check Debian packages for compliance with Debian policy. Every Debian maintainer should check packages with this tool before uploading them to the archive.
```

Two interesting lines from the description - (emphasis mine)

***It uses an archive directory, called laboratory, in which it stores information about the packages it examines.***

***Lintian dissects Debian packages and reports bugs and policy violations***

Now when you see an app. being debianized (meaning have the debian directory in the package/application sub-directory, for e.g. from https://github.com/eloaders/I-Nex.git

Thie app. has put compat level as 7

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~/games/I-Nex/debian] - [4360]
└─[$] cat compat

7
```

If we just bump the compat level to 9 from 7, will lintian tell me what needs to be fixed to be 9 compliant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, lintian doesn't verify compliance with the changes from one compatibility level to another. lintian is intended to verify policy compliance; how you use the build tools doesn't necessarily overlap with that.

There are a number of debhelper-related checks, but most of them are generic: making sure the debhelper build-dependency matches the compatibility level, that the declared compatibility level isn't obsolete, etc. You'll find them defined in [`checks/debhelper.pm`](https://salsa.debian.org/lintian/lintian/blob/master/checks/debhelper.pm). You can get a quick idea of the kinds of checks performed by reading the [tag descriptions](https://lintian.debian.org/tags.html); search for "debhelper", "dh-" or "dh_".

To determine what changes are required when transitioning from one compatibility level to another, you need to read the [`debhelper` documentation](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/debhelper/blob/master/debhelper.pod) (run `man debhelper`); that contains sections describing the changes from one compatibility level to another. You need to figure out whether and how these changes affect your package; very often the changes can't be automatically checked. Levels 8, 9 and 10 have introduced many features which help write more declarative `debian/rules` files, but it's up to you to take advantage of them; some of the changes can cause issues with older packages (in particular, multiarch support in level 9 and parallel builds in level 10).